I get error Can't set property because properties on edges are disabled in Memgraph
When I to run Memgraph MAGE inside docker, I get the following error:
CREATE ->(London)-[:LOCATED_IN {mark:['captial']}]->(England);

I get the error:
Client received query exception: Can't set property because properties on edges are disabled

If I use non-Docker version the same statement works fine.

Try running the docker version with the -storage-properties-on-edges=true flag.
